# Where does my Piggy Bank money go?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In **Animal Crossing: New Leaf,** I received a piggy bank from the *Post Office* as a reward for saving up **1,000,000 bells.** I was wondering what it did, so I put it on my *sleek table* and touched it. I heard a *Clink!*, which was the sound of money. I checked my inventory, and I found that **1** bell had been deducted from the **99,999** that I already had. I kept on inserting bells into the piggy bank. Where do my bells go? How can I get the bells I put inside the piggy bank back?

Comment: Have you tried putting the piggy bank back in your inventory?  It may give you the cash back then?

Comment: Actually, I haven't. Great idea! Let me try...

Comment: Sucks to lose those bells, could have lowered your ridiculous mortgage by 0.6%

Comment: Inflation can get pretty crazy when money literally grows on trees :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Piggy Bank does absolutely nothing but cost money. You cannot get the money back. And according to the IGN wiki it is unknown if there is a reward for putting bells in it: http://www.ign.com/wikis/animal-crossing-new-leaf/Piggy_Bank

It is a Lucky Item though and can contribute to your Feng Shui score no matter where you place it in the room: http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Feng_Shui

In previous games it was also worth 7,777 Happy Home Academy points. But I cannot find proof of that for New Leaf but this guide suggests it is true for City Folk: http://www.gamesradar.com/cheats/16074/

Several forums posts also reference the fact that your bells are gone forever. They go nowhere:

1. http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/997811-animal-crossing-new-leaf/answers?qid=354268
2. http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997811-animal-crossing-new-leaf/66502880

Comment: Please elaborate. What exactly will you earn by inserting bells that you cannot retrieve ever again? How do you know you cannot get the money back?

Comment: This still doesn't answer my question of where the money goes. Still, how would you know that I can never get the money back? I think Magaret's comment was the closest to an answer.

Comment: The money goes nowhere. It is gone forever. It is posted on several forums.

Comment: Jesus christ..... Looking back at my comments two years ago, I can see I was a bit obnoxious...

Answer (score 4):

Get the toy hammer from the gift shop and then click on it to smash it open then u get your money back and the post office sends you a new piggy bank

Answer (score 0):

Actually the bells that you put in the piggy bank go nowhere.  It was rumored that they go into your ATM, but that is not true. It is just wasting money.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, I found out that the price of the Piggy Bank at ReTail goes up by how much you put into it

Answer (score -3):

You don't get it back. All I can think is to save once you place it down and, if you put
a bell in, restart so you get it back.

Comment: Restart for one bell???